# Conditional statement to give different results elementwise when NA is total or partial

Tags: r, function, if-statement, tidyverse, dplyr

I have this data set with 6 variables containing either positive, negative or NA. A new column is required to be generated based on the values of these variables in the following manner:

`P` if ANY of the 6 variables contain a positive result.

`N` if NONE of the 6 variables contain a positive result.

`NA` if ALL of the 6 variables have `NA`.

**MWE**

```
var1 <- c('var1P', 'var1N', 'var1P', 'var1P', NA, 'var1N')
var2 <- c('var2N', 'var2N', 'var2N', 'var2P', NA, 'var2N')
var3 <- c('var3N', 'var3N', 'var3N', 'var3P', NA, 'var3N')
var4 <- c('var4P', 'var4N', 'var4P', 'var4P', NA, 'var4N')
var5 <- c(NA, 'var5N', 'var5N', 'var5P', NA, 'var5N')
var6 <- c(NA, NA, 'var6N', 'var6P', NA, 'var6N')
No <- seq(1:6)

df <- data.frame(No, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
```

**Code**

```
dfnew <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(varif = ifelse(var1 == 'var1P' | var2 == 'var2P' | var3 == 'var3P' | var4 == 'var4P' | var5 == 'var5P' | var6 == 'var6P', 'P', 'N'))
```

**Output**

```
  No  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 varif
   1 var1P var2N var3N var4P  <NA> <NA>      P
   2 var1N var2N var3N var4N var5N  <NA>   <NA>
   3 var1P var2N var3N var4P var5N var6N     P
   4 var1P var2P var3P var4P var5P var6P     P
   5  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>        <NA>
   6 var1N var2N var3N var4N var5N var6N     N
```

**Question**

the `varif` for No 2 should read `N` instead of `NA` to make it different from No 5 where all values were `NA`.

**Failed Trial**

```
impMe <- function (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6) {
  x <-ifelse(is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) & is.na(var3) & is.na(var4) & is.na(var5) & is.na(var6), NA,
             ifelse (var1 == 'var1P' | var2 == 'var2P' | var3 == 'var3P' | var4 == 'var4P' | var5 == 'var5P' | var6 == 'var6P','P','N'))
  return(x)
}

dfnew <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(varif = impMe(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6))

  No  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 varif
   1 var1P var2N var3N var4P  <NA> <NA>      P
   2 var1N var2N var3N var4N var5N  <NA>   <NA>
   3 var1P var2N var3N var4P var5N var6N     P
   4 var1P var2P var3P var4P var5P var6P     P
   5  <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA>    <NA>
   6 var1N var2N var3N var4N var5N var6N     N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have answered your question yourself, still I feel that your answer is too verbose as you have to type manually all column names....

usage of `all` , `any` in conjunction with `c_across` is suggested.  I therefore, propose this solution which will without typing manually the column names

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise %>%
  mutate(varif = case_when(any(substr(c_across(!No), nchar(c_across(!No)), nchar(c_across(!No))) == 'P') ~ 'P',
                           all(is.na(c_across(!No))) ~ NA_character_,
                           TRUE ~ 'N'))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      No var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  varif
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 var1P var2N var3N var4P <NA>  <NA>  P    
#> 2     2 var1N var2N var3N var4N var5N <NA>  N    
#> 3     3 var1P var2N var3N var4P var5N var6N P    
#> 4     4 var1P var2P var3P var4P var5P var6P P    
#> 5     5 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 6     6 var1N var2N var3N var4N var5N var6N N
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

in tidyverse there is a gem called `case_when()`, it does the multi-case ifelse(). I commented out the line for `NA` because it was not needed as `case_when()` will return `NA` if all mentioned conditions were not met which makes this line unnecessary!

```
dfnew <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(varif = case_when (
                  ## is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) & is.na(var3) & is.na(var4) & is.na(var5) & is.na(var6) ~ NA,
                  var1 == 'var1P' | var2 == 'var2P' | var3 == 'var3P' | var4 == 'var4P' | var5 == 'var5P' | var6 == 'var6P' ~ 'P',
                  !is.na(var1) | !is.na(var2) | !is.na(var3) | !is.na(var4) | !is.na(var5) | !is.na(var6) ~ 'N'
                  ))
```

**Output**

[image]